# Write XML to Project (iOS, Xcode 4)

Tags: ios, xml

I think there just isn't a solution to my problem, but I was hoping someone might have a creative work-a-round from past experience to share. I have created a 3D level editor for my latest iPhone/iPad game, and I am at the final stage where I need to write the map out into an XML file format I've devised.

I'm using KISSXML as my XML library for parsing, and I'm getting ready to extend my use of it to writing as well.  My question is this:  is it possible to somehow write to a location that I can view and then store in the project?  For the initial 20-30 map files I create, I want to directly import them into the project as resources that could be edited later as text files too...  I don't want them stored as app resources yet at this stage (but I've heard you cannot write from an app to the resources structure for a project?).  Is there some creative way to even just send myself the XML or write it in a location I can retrieve it easily?  When I extend the editor to be a usable tool by players, writing to the app directory will be great - but for now, that is not what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions or tips would be fantastic!

Here's a snippet I'm using to write out at the moment.  I guess an even simpler question is: where does this go?  Is it somewhere I can access outside of my app?  Is there some way to write it so that it is more accessible to me?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xmlfile.xml", documentsDirectory];

DDXMLDocument* document = [[[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<addresses/>" options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
DDXMLElement* root = [document rootElement];
[root addChild:[DDXMLNode elementWithName:@"address" stringValue:@"Some Address"]];

NSData *xmlData = [document XMLDataWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint];
if (![xmlData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not write document out...");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using the following line:

```
NSLog(@"Documents: %@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I can get access via finder in OSX to my documents directory and view/edit the XML file I've written.  This of course only works when I generate the file using the simulator, not the device.  This is looking more and more like a problem without a solution...  I suppose I could email the XML file as an attachment to myself as a cheap hack?  Not my preferred solution, but may have to do for now.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Stackoverflow...

Comment: I'm sorry, this is kind of embarrassing... is that something I can do, or does a higher ranked user have to do it for me?  I agree, on second thought this is a fairly broad question.

Comment: Don't sweat it. A moderator will do it for you.

Comment: I've flagged it - anyone can flag as off topic and the moderators are great about taking care of things if they agree. It's so much better to ask a good question than be unfamiliar with how the sites have at present divvied up the topics :-)

Comment: re the question when you say edit later - do you mean by the app or just improving them before release?

Comment: Improving them before release...  just by hand, if some minor edits were needed outside of the editor.

Comment: I mean, the problem is this: I am using the app itself to create levels for the game. The thing is, I want the initial levels built for launch to be included in the game itself, not in the app's documents directory - is that sensible, or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: The issue is that in production you can't save to the app's bundle - but you can in dev so the xml can be added to Xcode

Comment: Mark, how do I go about doing that in dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to inspect the files your app creates. Several possible solutions come to mind. You could

1. enable Itunes Files Sharing by setting the [UIFileSharingEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) property in your application's info.plist.
2. implement Dropbox
3. make your app post the file to a webserver you have in your local network.

Option 1 is probably the easiest to setup, but you have to make some clicks to get to your data.
If you have a webserver running anyway I would probably go for option 3.

Comment: Agreed, both options 1 and 3 would work great (especially 3).  I'll be working on something similar to item #3 down the road anyway, so that's probably the way to go.  Out of curiosity, how do you get to the files if you enable UIFileSharing in iTunes?

Comment: With UIFileSharing enabled, you can access an application's file through iTunes. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is exactly what I was hoping for!  Much appreciation!!

Answer (score 0):

Without hearing from anyone, I'm assuming this is fairly impossible to do.  I'm switching gears and now both A) saving the map to the apps directory for future loading, and B) emailing a copy of the XML to myself for extraction and then manual integration with the project.  Not the ideal solution I hoped for, but it does work.

Hope this helps anyone else curious down the road.